# How to fetch data from Sqlite in android .data is storing with one activity while fetching another activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I am storing token & userId in sqlite with one activity as per below:

Name - To get "userId" & "token" storing in sqlite database.

SQLiteHandler - To store "userID" & "token".

signup - in this activity, i want to fetch "userId" & "token" which is  already stored in Sqlite via Name activity.

How can i do this ?

Name

```
public class Name extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = Name.class.getSimpleName();

    private Button btn_name_next;
    EditText emailid,editTextUserName;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private SessionManager session;
    private SQLiteHandler db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name);
        btn_name_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_name_next);
        //emailid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailid);
        editTextUserName=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        final String tmDevice, tmSerial, androidId;
        tmDevice = "" + tm.getDeviceId();
        tmSerial = "" + tm.getSimSerialNumber();
        androidId = "" + Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        UUID deviceUuid = new UUID(androidId.hashCode(), ((long) tmDevice.hashCode() << 32) | tmSerial.hashCode());
        final String deviceId = deviceUuid.toString();
        Log.e(TAG, "Device Id: " + deviceId);
        // Progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // SQLite database handler
        db = new SQLiteHandler(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Name.this,
                    MakemeHealthy.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }



        btn_name_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



          //      String id = emailid.getText().toString();
                String name=editTextUserName.getText().toString();

                if (name.length()==0) {

                    editTextUserName.setError("Tell us your name atleast");

                }


                else
                {
                    //launchAgeScreen();
                    registerUser(name, deviceId);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void registerUser(final String name, final String deviceId) {


            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_string_req = "req_register";

            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            showDialog();

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.NAME_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jObj.getBoolean("success");
                        //boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (success) {
                            // User successfully stored in MySQL
                            // Now store the user in sqlite
                            //String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                            String userId =jObj.getString("userId");
                            String token = jObj.getString("token");

                            db.addUser( token,userId);
                            //db.addUser(userId);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Launch login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Name.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                            // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                            // message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting params to register url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("name", name);
                    //params.put("email", email);
                   // params.put("password", password);
                    params.put("deviceId", deviceId);


                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    private void launchAgeScreen() {
        startActivity(new Intent(Name.this, Age.class));
       finish();
    }
}
```

SQLiteHandler

```
public class SQLiteHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SQLiteHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    //public static final String KEY_USERID = ;
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.a98fit.neeraj.a98fit/databases/";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_USER = "user";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_TOKEN = "token";
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "userId";

    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TOKEN + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_USERID + " TEXT"  + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_USER);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at
     * */
    public void addUser(String token , String userId  ) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_TOKEN, token);
        values.put(KEY_USERID, userId);

         // Email
         // Email
        //values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        long id = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

        Log.d(TAG, "New user inserted into sqlite: " + id);
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

            //user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            //user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("token", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("userId", cursor.getString(2));
            //user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        Log.d(TAG, "Fetching user from Sqlite: " + user.toString());

        return user;
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }


    /**
     * Re crate database Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void deleteUsers() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_USER, null, null);
        db.close();

        Log.d(TAG, "Deleted all user info from sqlite");
    }

/*  public  String getYourData() {
        {
             final String TABLE_USER = "user";



            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_USER;
            SQLiteDatabase db  = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor      = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            String data      = null;

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    // get the data into array, or class variable
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            return getYourData();
        }
    }*/


}
```

Signup :

```
// Make Me Awesome Button Click event
        btn_name_make.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = editTextEmailid.getText().toString();
                String password = passwordentry.getText().toString();
                SQLiteHandler myDatabaseHelper = new SQLiteHandler(Signup.this);
                myDatabaseHelper.openDataBase();
                HashMap<String, String> rs =  myDatabaseHelper.getUserDetails();

                myDatabaseHelper.close();
                if (email.length() == 0) {

                    editTextEmailid.setError("Please Enter Email id");

                } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())

                {
                    editTextEmailid.setError("Please enter Valid Email id");

                } else if (password.length() == 0) {

                    passwordentry.setError("Please Enter password");

                } else if (password.length() < 6) {

                    passwordentry.setError("Please Enter minimum 6 character");
                } else {

                    registerUser(token,userId,email,password);
                }


            }
        });
```

Device Id ,token:

```
 private void registerUser(final String name, final String deviceId) {


            // Tag used to cancel the request
            String tag_string_req = "req_register";

            pDialog.setMessage("Registering ...");
            showDialog();

            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                    AppConfig.NAME_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());
                    hideDialog();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = jObj.getBoolean("success");
                        //boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        if (success) {
                            // User successfully stored in MySQL
                            // Now store the user in sqlite
                            //String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                            String userId =jObj.getString("userId");
                            String token = jObj.getString("token");

                            db.addUser( token,userId);
                            //db.addUser(userId);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User successfully registered. Try login now!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            // Launch login activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Name.this,
                                    MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {

                            // Error occurred in registration. Get the error
                            // message
                            String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

 @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hideDialog();
                }
            }) {

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    // Posting params to register url
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("name", name);
                    //params.put("email", email);
                   // params.put("password", password);
                    params.put("deviceId", deviceId);


                    return params;
                }

            };

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
    }
```

Comment: In which part of the signUp?

Comment: @JohnJoe 
        // Make Me Awesome Button Click event

Comment: You want to check whether the data already exists ?

Comment: @JohnJoe   
No, I have to send parameter to call api for signup of user. /*api/* will always require a token and userId, which is already stored with Name Activity. I have required token & userId to hit API to signup.

Comment: In signUp class, you have this `HashMap<String, String> rs =  myDatabaseHelper.getUserDetails();`. What does this line for ? call the method and retrieve the user details?

Comment: @John Joe was trying to get the details . I don't know how to do this ? please tell me how can i get ?

Comment: If the token and userId exists, will go to `registerUser(token,userId,email,password);` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes because First it was registered with only name only while registered with name i have stored "device id " in sqlite and get token and userID fro same

Comment: give me some time..i will write the answer for you once i back from work

Comment: @JohnJoe Okay thanks

Comment: I'm writing the answer now

Comment: @JohnJoe okay thank you

Comment: can you show  `db.addUser( token,userId);`?

Comment: @JohnJoe check i have edit code you will find at last

Comment: I need to know the flow of your activity. In where the signUp class get called ?

Comment: After Name, then MainActivity. When you call the SignUp?

Comment: First NameActivity then Signup.Main Activity for login .

Comment: You can just pass id and token from Name to SignUp.You said  Name will be called than follow by SignUp, but in button click you call MainActivity, not SignUp.

Comment: I will change this but how to get userId and token from sqlite This is the main problem

Comment: To make it clear, your class flow is Name,SignUp,then Main ?

Comment: Yes it is final

Comment: why not using `intent.putExtra()` to pass the id and token to SignUp ?

Comment: How to send Could you please tell  me code ?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the data to another Activity, you can achieve like this

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Name.this, SignUP.class);
 intent.putExtra("id", id);
 intent.putExtra("token",token);
 startActivity(intent);
```

To receive in your **SignUp**

```
int id,token // declare them in global

 id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
 token = getIntent().getIntExtra("token",0);
```

Comment: how will i get id and token in signup ?